# Sitecore 8: Datasource value is null/empty in sublayout(.ascx)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am trying to access datasource value of sublayout through code behind and I get empty string in a data source.

Below are the screen shots of my Banner sublayout in sitecore and how the datasource value is set in presentation:

[Banner Sublayout with Datasource location and template set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMXLI.png)

[Banner sublayout added to presentation and datasource set to an item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQ2qz.png)

Below is the code that I am using to retrieve datasource:

```
    using Sitecore.Data.Items;
    using Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System;
    using System.Web.UI;

    public partial class Banner : UserControl
    {
        private Item _dataSource = null;
        public Item DataSource
        {
            get
            {
                if (_dataSource == null)
                    if (Parent is Sublayout)
                    {
                        _dataSource = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(((Sublayout)Parent).DataSource);
                    }
                return _dataSource;
            }
        }
        private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var test = DataSource;
            Item a = Sitecore.Context.Item;
        }
    }
```

Am I doing anything wrong or what could be the issue?

Comment: Are all relevant items published (current item, datasource, ..)? Can you verify in the web database..

Comment: And off-topic: use "as" instead of "is" if you are going to cast ;)

Comment: @Gatogordo - "as" is for casting, "is" is for checking inheritance.  They're not interchangeable unless you were suggesting he does a cast using "as" and replaced his "if" statement with a check for null, i.e., checking if the "as cast worked.

Comment: try changing your context database to master and see if the issue still exists? if not something to do with publishing.

Answer (score 0):

What if you get your item renderings:

```
RenderingReference[] renderings = currentItem.GetRenderings();
```

Then, get the rendering you want using:

```
var rendering = renderings.Where(r => r.RenderingItem.ID != yourRenderingID)
```

And Finally,

```
rendering.Settings.DataSource  //This is the datasource id
```